# How to debug a simulated browser client of socket.io in node.js server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have simulated a browser client of socket.io  in the node.js server

I am creating the simulated browser client when particular message arrived from a Real browser client.

```
     console.log('creating client of '+sessionId);
    var socket=client.init();

    console.log(socket);
```

here is my Simulated browser client in node.js , I am using https://github.com/saschagehlich/node-socket.io-client for creating client.

```
exports.init=function(){
    var socket = new io.Socket(config.host, {port: config.port, rememberTransport: false});
    // when connected, clear out display
    socket.on('connect',function() {
        console.log('dummy user connected');
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
        console.log('disconnected dummy');
    });
    socket.on('message', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
    socket.connect();
    return socket;
};
```

Comment: problem was in my declaration of config , not given the var , now its running .